# How to integrate ccavenue payment gateway in ionic with angular

Tags: angular, ionic4, payment, ccavenue

In my app, I need payment gateway of CCavenue. Please give me steps for that Issue.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

step 1:install https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/in-app-browser

step 2:InAppBrowser. loadstart('http://apache.org', '_blank', 'hidden=yes');
pass ur payment ccavenue url